# Is there a way to make my page responsive in html?

Tags: html, css

This is my code which I want to make responsive. I tried to add media queries, but I couldn't figure out how to make it work with my code. I even tried setting the width to 100%, but still I don't know how it works. A simple explanation of how to sort it out would be very helpful for me. Thank you in advance.

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Web Development course</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css"> 
</head>

<body>


<svg id = "rect1"></svg>
<svg id = "rect2"></svg>
<svg id = "rect3"></svg>



<a href = "htmlCourse/htmlcourse.html"> <img id = "html" src ="images/html.png"></a>
<a href = "cssCourse/csscourse.html"> <img id = "css" src ="images/css.png"></a>
<a href = "jsCourse/jscourse.html"> <img id = "js" src ="images/js.png"></a>

<style>
    h, a{
        font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: bold;
        line-height: 41px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
        
     }
     img:hover{opacity: 0.6; transform: scale(1.2); transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;}
     img:not(:hover){transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;}
     a:hover{text-shadow: 0 4px 4px rgb(0, 0, 0); transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;}
     a:not(:hover){transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;}

 </style>

 <h style= "top: 27px;">Web Development Course</h>
 <a id = "getstarted" href="#droppage">Get Started</a>

 <ul id = "menu"> 

    <li><a id = "cinfo" > <img style="left: -10px; top: 18px;"id = "drop" src = 
 "images/drop.png"> Course Info</a>

        <ul>

           <li><a id = "htm" href="htmlCourse/htmlcourse.html">HTML</a>

               <ul>
                   <li><a id = "lec" href="htmlCourse/htmlcourse.html">Lectures</a>
                   <li><a id = "tut" href="htmlCourse/htmlcourse.html">Tutorial</a>
                   <li><a id = "Lab" href="htmlCourse/htmlcourse.html">Labs</a>
               </ul>

           </li>

           <li><a id = "cs" href="cssCourse/csscourse.html">CSS</a>

               <ul>
                   <li><a id = "cslec" href="cssCourse/csscourse.html">Lectures</a>
                   <li><a id = "cstut1" href="cssCourse/csscourse.html">Tutorial</a>
                   <li><a id = "csLab1" href="cssCourse/csscourse.html">Labs</a>
               </ul>

           </li>    

           <li><a id = "java" href="jsCourse/jscourse.html">JavaScript</a>

               <ul>
                   <li><a id = "javalec" href="jsCourse/jscourse.html">Lectures</a>
                   <li><a id = "javatut" href="jsCourse/jscourse.html">Tutorial</a>
                   <li><a id = "javaLab" href="jsCourse/jscourse.html">Labs</a>
               </ul>

           </li>

        </ul>
        
    </li>
        
 </ul>

 <a id = "droparrow" href="#droppage" > <img  style="left: -40px; top: 0px widt;"id = "drop2" 
 src = "images/drop.png"> </a>
 <a style="position: absolute; bottom: 20px; left: 700px;" name="droppage"></a>
 <a id = "droparrow" href="#uppage" > <img  style="left: -40px; top: 0px widt;"id = "drop3" 
 src = "images/drop.png"> </a>
 <a style="position: absolute; top: -8px; left: 700px;" name="uppage"></a>
 


 </body>
 </html>
```

**css**

```
 body{

position: absolute;
width: 1440px;
height: 2420px;
background-color: #383C46;

}

#rect1{

position: absolute;
width: 1400px;
height: 59px;
left: 250px;
top: 20px;
background: #3F5577;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
#rect2{

position: absolute;
width: 59px;
height: 0px;
left: 692px;
top: 49px;
border: 1px solid #383C46;
transform: rotate(90deg);    
}
#rect3{

position: absolute;
width: 166px;
height: 59px;
left: 1470px;
top: 20px;

}
#drop{
position: absolute;
left: 795px;
top: 34px;
width: 30px;
height: 35px;

}
#drop2{
position: absolute;
left: 795px;
top: 34px;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;

}
#drop3{
position: absolute;
left: 795px;
top: 700px;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
transform: rotate(180deg); 
}
h{

position: relative;
width: 317px;
height: 59px;
left: 389px;
top: 26px;
font-size: 25px;

}
#cinfo{
position: absolute;
top: 5px;
left: 20px;
font-size: 20px;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}
#getstarted{

position: absolute;
text-transform: uppercase;
width: 317px;
height: 59px;
left: 1000px;
top: 30px;
font-size: 20px;
text-decoration: none;
}
#html{
position: absolute;
width: 200px;
height: 280.26px;
left: 400px;
top: 1800px;
}
#css{
position: absolute;
width: 200px;
height: 280.26px;
left: 850px;
top: 1800px;    
}
#js{
position: absolute;
width: 200px;
height: 280.26px;
left: 1300px;
top: 1800px;
}
#droparrow{
position: absolute;
left: 67%;
top: 35%;
}
#menu, #menu ul{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}
#menu{
position: absolute;
width: 900px;
left: 721px;
top: 12px;
border-radius: 6px;
}
#menu::before, #menu::after{
content: '';
display: table;
}
#menu:after{
clear: both;
}
#menu li{
float: left;
box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #444;
}
#menu a{
float: left;
padding: 12px 30px;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
}
#menu ul{
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 70px;
left: 1px;
z-index: 1;
background:#383C46;
transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
#menu li:hover > ul{
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
margin: 0;
background: rgb(58, 67, 94);
}
#menu ul ul{
top: 0;
left: 150px;
margin: 0 0 0 20px;

}
#menu ul li{
float: none;
display: block;
border: 0; 

background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
text-align: center;
}
#menu ul a{
padding: 10px;
width: 130px;
display: block;
white-space: nowrap;
float: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
#menu ul a:hover{
background: rgb(31, 31, 44);
}
```

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: ...and don't use fixed pixel widths to size your elements, use % etc instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you try and use percentages instead of pixels while setting properties like the width to your elements. Try and also avoid using IDs for styling because I think they are mainly meant for DOM manipulation.
Always ensure that you group your HTML elements in a single container if at all you want your page to be responsive. So you can add:

```
<div class="container">
   //page contents
</div>
```

and then ensure all your contents are inside that container.
You can also wrap your navigation elements inside the nav element. e.g

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/"></a></li>
    <li><a href="/"></a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Such are the best practices that you should ensure that you follow while writing code.